# Aggregates in Nest (Elastic) with filter having both nested and parent objects

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, parent-child, aggregates

I have a catalog of products that I want to calculate aggregates on. The trouble comes with trying to do nested aggregations with filter that has both nested and parent fields in it. Either it gives wrong counts or 0 hits. Here is a sample of my product object mapping:

```
"Products": {
        "properties": {
           "ProductID": {
              "type": "long"
           },
           "ProductType": {
              "type": "long"
           },
           "ProductName": {
              "type": "string",
              "fields": {
                 "raw": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                 }
              }
           },
           "Prices": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                 "CurrencyType": {
                    "type": "integer"
                 },
                 "Cost": {
                    "type": "double"                        
                 }
              }
          } 
      }
  }
```

Here is an example of the sql query that I am trying to replicate in elastic:

```
SELECT PRODPR.Cost AS PRODPR_Cost 
    ,COUNT(PROD.ProdcutID) AS PROD_ProductID_Count
FROM Products PROD WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Prices PRODPR WITH (NOLOCK) ON (PRODPR.objectid = PROD.objectid)
WHERE PRODPR.CurrencyType = 4
    AND PROD.ProductType IN (
        11273
        ,11293
        ,11294
        )
GROUP BY PRODPR.Cost
```

Elastic Search queries I came up with:
First One (following query returns correct counts with just CurrencyType as filter but when I add ProductType filter, it gives me wrong counts)

```
GET /IndexName/Products/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "price_agg": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          **"must": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "Prices",
                    "filter": {
                      "term": {
                        "Prices.CurrencyType": "8"
                      }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "ProductType": [
                  "11273",
                  "11293",
                  "11294"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]**
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "price_nested_agg": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "Prices"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "59316518_group_agg": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "Prices.Cost",
                "size": 0
              },
              "aggs": {
                "product_count": {
                    "reverse_nested": { },
                    "aggs": {
                        "ProductID_count_agg": {
                            "value_count": {
                                "field": "ProductID"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Second One (following query returns correct counts with just CurrencyType as filter but when I add ProductType filter, it gives me 0 hits):

```
GET /IndexName/Prodcuts/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "price_agg": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "Prices"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "currency_filter": {
          "filter": {
              "bool": {
                  "must": [
                     {
                         "term": {
                            "Prices.CurrrencyType": "4"
                         }
                     },
                     {
                         "terms": {
                            "ProductType": [
                               "11273",
                               "11293"
                            ]
                         }
                     }
                  ]
              }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "59316518_group_agg": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "Prices.Cost",
                "size": 0
              },
              "aggs": {
                "product_count": {
                  "reverse_nested": {},
                  "aggs": {
                    "ProductID_count_agg": {
                      "value_count": {
                        "field": "ProductID"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

I have tried some more queries but the above two are the closest I came up with. Has anyone come across this use case? What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!